# Evaluating CSharpScript throws a Method not found

Tags: c#, roslyn, dnx

I'm having a problem trying to evaluate a CSharpScript. I'm running on dnx46, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 1.2.0-rc. I'm suspecting the problem to lie within conflicts between mscorlib and CoreFx.

Here is one of the code snippets that has failed:

```
private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _environment;
private readonly ILibraryExporter _exporter;

var references = _exporter.GetAllExports(_environment.ApplicationName).MetadataReferences;
var options = ScriptOptions.Default
            .AddReferences(references.Select(x => ConvertMetadataReference(x)))
            .AddImports("System.Collections.Generic", "System.Linq");
var result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("1+1");
```

(My ApplicationEnvironment and LibraryExporter is being passed in by dnx at startup, neither of these are null).

Upon trying to run `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync`, the following exception is thrown.

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilationOptions..ctor
(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.OutputKind, Boolean, System.String, System.String, System.String,
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>,
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.OptimizationLevel, Boolean, Boolean, System.String, System.String, 
System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Byte>, 
System.Nullable`1<Boolean>, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Platform, 
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ReportDiagnostic, 
Int32, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2
<System.String,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ReportDiagnostic>>, Boolean, Boolean,
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.XmlReferenceResolver, 
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SourceReferenceResolver, 
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReferenceResolver,
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AssemblyIdentityComparer,
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.StrongNameProvider, Boolean)'
```

I [dumped the list of references in my ScriptOptions](http://hastebin.com/izuwetexob.avrasm), not sure if that shows anything.

While I'm not truly sure what the issue with my code is, I'm assuming that it has to due with me running this project under dnx46, as I had to override the basic assemblies (System, System.Runtime, etc) in my [project.json](http://hastebin.com/kofiwemewi.dos).

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to

```
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting": "1.1.1",
"Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

has fixed the problem.

Not sure why it was an issue in the first place, but the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

this happens if there is somehow a version conflict e.g. 2.8 version does not have this contractor and it might resolve this version from your dependecies instead of the project version